# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/parquet/schema/LogicalTypeAnnotation$UUIDLogicalTypeAnnotation while fetching data from Hudi

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-hudi

I am trying to view some data from Hudi using below code in spark.

```scala
import org.apache.hudi.DataSourceReadOptions;
val hudiIncQueryDF = spark
  .read()
  .format("hudi")
  .option(DataSourceReadOptions.QUERY_TYPE, DataSourceReadOptions.QUERY_TYPE_SNAPSHOT_OPT_VAL())
  .load("load path name")
```

I am runing this code using jupyter notebook by creating a dataproc cluster. I have added the jar while creating the cluster using below

```
  --properties spark:spark.jars.packages=org.apache.hudi:hudi-spark3.2-bundle_2.12:0.11.0 \
```

However, i am getting below error while running the code

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/parquet/schema/LogicalTypeAnnotation$UUIDLogicalTypeAnnotation
  at org.apache.hudi.common.table.TableSchemaResolver.convertParquetSchemaToAvro(TableSchemaResolver.java:340)
  at org.apache.hudi.common.table.TableSchemaResolver.getTableAvroSchemaFromDataFile(TableSchemaResolver.java:148)
  at org.apache.hudi.common.table.TableSchemaResolver.hasOperationField(TableSchemaResolver.java:565)
  at org.apache.hudi.common.table.TableSchemaResolver.<init>(TableSchemaResolver.java:82)
  at org.apache.hudi.HoodieBaseRelation.x$1$lzycompute(HoodieBaseRelation.scala:126)
  at org.apache.hudi.HoodieBaseRelation.x$1(HoodieBaseRelation.scala:125)
  at org.apache.hudi.HoodieBaseRelation.tableAvroSchema$lzycompute(HoodieBaseRelation.scala:125)
  at org.apache.hudi.HoodieBaseRelation.tableAvroSchema(HoodieBaseRelation.scala:125)
  at org.apache.hudi.HoodieBaseRelation.<init>(HoodieBaseRelation.scala:147)
  at org.apache.hudi.BaseFileOnlyRelation.<init>(BaseFileOnlyRelation.scala:53)
  at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.resolveBaseFileOnlyRelation(DefaultSource.scala:217)
  at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:113)
  at org.apache.hudi.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:305)
  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:265)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
  ... 37 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.parquet.schema.LogicalTypeAnnotation$UUIDLogicalTypeAnnotation
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
  ... 56 more
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you verified with gcloud Spark job submit or spark-submit? There is a known issue with Jupyter notebook.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use an init action to download the jar to `/usr/lib/spark/jars`.